# How can I fork a Perl CGI program to hive off long-running tasks?

Tags: perl, cgi, fork

I am writing a Bulk Mail scheduler controlled from a Perl/CGI Application and would like to learn abut "good" ways to fork a CGI program to run a separate task? Should one do it at all? Or is it better to suffer the overhead of running a separate job-queue engine like [Gearman](http://www.gearman.org/) or [TheSchwartz](http://search.cpan.org/~bradfitz/TheSchwartz-1.07/lib/TheSchwartz.pm) as has been [suggested recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942749/scheduling-one-time-tasks-from-a-perl-cgi-application). Does the answer/perspective change when using an near-MVC framework like CGI::Application over vanilla CGI.pm? The last comes from a possible project that I have in mind for a CGI::Application Plugin - that would make "forking" a process relatively simple to call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at Proc::Daemon - it's the simplest thing that works. From your CGI script, do the CGI business (getting input, returning a response to the browser), then call Proc::Daemon::init() which does the fork, daemonizes your process and makes the parent exit. Then your script (now a daemon) does its long-running tasks and exits when they're done.
You'll want to update something (file, database record) while running as a daemon, so subsequent CGI invocations can check what it did (or how it's progressing).

Answer (score 0):

Would something like [POE](http://poe.perl.org/) be useful? It's more event-driven than forked, but it may meet your needs.